# How to add "alt text" in Latex

Tags: graphics

I need to add alt text to all my figures in latex. This is for the purpose of writing a book chapter.I tried using \Description command which did not work. I also tried using alt text inside \includegraphics. Can anyone help me out to write alt text in latex. A sample script which I have tried is given below:

```
    \documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[alt={Alternative text},width=\linewidth]{Figures/myfig.pdf}
    % \alt{Alt text}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{fig1}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: What should the alt text do?

Comment: I believe `alt=` is the correct thing, and should work on an updated TeX.  But that alt text is not visible, and gets read by a screen reader.  Is it possible you think it didn't work because you didn't see it?  In which case, to echo mickep, what are you expecting to have happen?

Comment: Are you looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703340/36296 ?

Comment: @mickep Alt text is an accessibility aid used by screen readers.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL screen readers reading html... or tagged pdf but not classic untagged pdf, as such `alt=` does nothing by default in latex but is used by tagpdf when creating tagged pdf and used (originally) by tex4ht when creating html

Comment: @Teepeemm "work" for some definition of work. It is defined in recent graphicx releases but does nothing.

Comment: @mickep Alt text is a short text description that can be digitally attached to figures or images to convey to readers the nature or contents of the image. It is used by systems such as pronouncing screen readers to make the object accessible to people that cannot read or see the object due to a visual impairment or print disability.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, it is not visibile in the pdf. I was expecting the alt text to pop up when a cursor is placed on the image.

Comment: @AbhiramBR What you describe is a 'tool tip' in PDF terms. With a tagged PDF, there are `alt` keys but these don't just 'appear', they are used by e.g. screen readers when speaking a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.

A general remark: Just in case you need [some material on LaTeX, here are some](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner).

Following [samCs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz) hint [How do I define alt text on images in tagpdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703339/how-do-i-define-alt-text-on-images-in-tagpdf/703340#703340) the correct syntax should be, adjusted a little bit:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III}
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}% not needed in this example

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[alt={Alternative text},width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    % \alt{Alt text}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{fig1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I can't test it, as my installation may be incomplete (or I entered a stupid mistake too early in the morning), concluding from compile errors:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%%\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%%\usepackage{caption}
%%\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
hi
%    \begin{figure}[h]
%    \centering
%    \includegraphics[alt={Alternative text},width=\textwidth]{example-image}
%    % \alt{Alt text}
%    \caption{My caption}
%    \label{fig1}
%    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: errors]

However, as [Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [explains here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686905/245790) it appears to me that what you want is just in the process of being implemented.

So in worst case you may have to drop the alt-text feature for now.

Comment: Have you got the latest `expl3`, etc.? For me, there is one error, related to footnotes, and I do get a PDF out

Comment: Probably not. Will run an update later. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @JosephWright, even after updating packages this one seems to be missing, at least: `l3bitset.sty` . No idea, how to add theat via MiKTeX Console.

Comment: `l3bistset` was integrated into the `expl3` core in the 2023-12-08 release - have you got an up-to-date system across the board? Usual MiKTeX advice applies: update both as 'you' and as Admin.

Comment: @JosephWright, thank you. Well, I'm the only and local user. For the time being I'll take it as it is ;-) Thanks again